# Get the currency from current culture?

Tags: c#, currency, cultureinfo

Is there a way to get current information dynamically from the apps culture settings?  Basically if the user has set the culture to US I want to know the currency is dollars, or if they have it set to UK I want to pound sterling etc... etc..

This is so I can send this information to PayPal when a payment is being made

Comment: I think paypal expects "USD" which is ISO Currency Code.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Use the RegionInfo.ISOCurrencySymbol property.  For example:

```
  var ri = new RegionInfo(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.LCID);
  Console.WriteLine(ri.ISOCurrencySymbol);
```

Output: "USD"

Comment: This should work perfectly! I'll try it this afternoon and mark as the answer if it works :)  Thanks

Answer (score 43):

You can get the *symbol* from `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol`, but I doubt this is enough; you may need to maintain a separate list per culture. Or just let the user tell you what they want to pay in (for example, they might be away from home, etc, so the culture of the PC in some hotel lounge *isn't* what is on their credit card)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for but you have to import System.Globalization first. Thanks

Answer (score 27):

Once you have the CultureInfo ci object, you can ask such as

```
ci.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol
```

For current culture, you will simply do

```
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol
```

Comment: Not necessariy good enough as the currency SYMBOL may not be unique.

Comment: This will return not ISO currency symbols. For example instead of EUR you will get euro symbol like € .

Answer (score 6):

```
string isoCurrencySymbol = RegionInfo.CurrentRegion.ISOCurrencySymbol;
```

Comment: The ISOCurrencySymbol is the 3-letter code (e.g., USD). The symbol or sign (e.g., $) as retrieved by NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol, is NOT unique.

Comment: Just a warning that CurrentRegion does NOT come from the current UI culture, and changing the culture of the current thread will not change CurrentRegion - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.regioninfo.currentregion?view=netframework-4.8 To do that see the answer by @Hans Passant

Comment: @herostwist for most app the OS setting is the one to use. So no issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can basically use CultureInfo class

```
CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo(UICulture);
var symbol = ci.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol;
```

Comment: Not good enough - sorry. THe currency symbol is not the currency - there is no requirement for that being unique.

Answer (score 2):

```
    public static string GetCurrencySymbol(string currency)
    {
        if (currency == null) return "";
        if (currency == "") return "";
        int i = 0;
        var regionInfo = new RegionInfo(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.LCID);
        foreach (var cultureInfo in CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures & ~CultureTypes.NeutralCultures))
        {
            if (!cultureInfo.Equals(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
            {
                var regionCulture = new RegionInfo(cultureInfo.LCID);

                    if(regionCulture.ISOCurrencySymbol == currency)
                    {
                        //list.Add(regionCulture);
                        regionInfo = regionCulture;
                    }
                }
        }
```

Comment: O(N) search each time?? Why not make it a recursive function and do some memoization?

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me.

```
var c = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures)
      .Select(t=> new RegionInfo(t.LCID))
      .Where(t=>t.ThreeLetterISORegionName  == "USA")
      .FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

http://help.outlook.com/en-us/140/system.globalization.regioninfo.currencynativename(VS.85).aspx

You'll want the RegionInfo.CurrencyNativeName, RegionInfo.CurrencyEnglishName or RegionInfo.ISOCurrencySymbol