# How to get system currency symbol to a string

Tags: c#, console-application

If I do this:

```
Console.Write("The sum is {0:c}", 12);
```

I'm on a Swedish computer so it'll return:
**The sum is 12,00 kr**

But is there a simple way of getting just the currency symbol, without a number?
Like this (obviously this doesn't work, but just to show what I'm after):

```
 Console.Write("The symbol is {c}");
```

I would like that to output: **The symbol is kr**

Comment: Googling "currency symbol .net" gave me:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencysymbol.aspx

Comment: Related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763128/get-the-currency-from-current-culture

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This code should return the currency symbol you're looking for.

```
System.Globalization.RegionInfo.CurrentRegion.CurrencySymbol
```

You could also use the following instead to get the ISO currency symbol

```
System.Globalization.RegionInfo.CurrentRegion.ISOCurrencySymbol
```

Comment: Thank you. That ISO option looks better in this specific case.

Comment: Are there any certain standards (or opinions) on if it's better to use RegionInfo or CultureInfo?

Comment: @Tophe According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.regioninfo.currentregion.aspx), `System.Globalization.RegionInfo.CurrentRegion` is based on the culture selected through the regional and language options portion of Control Panel.  I think CultureInfo can be changed by your application on the fly.

Answer (score 14):

You can use:

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get it off of the [NumberFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.aspx) in the CurrentCulture:

```
Console.Write(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol)
```

Comment: That returns a $ for me, and I'm pretty sure I'm in the UK ;). It needs to be `CurrentCulture` not `CurrentUICulture`.