# C# currency formatting ("C2")

Tags: c#, currency

I have learned how to make a string variable display in currency format using C2. But how would I be able to display in other currencies such as Euros.

Below is my foundation code to work from

```
        Console.WriteLine("\nHere is the same value displayed in currency form: " + value.ToString("C2"));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proper currency format when not displaying the native currency of a culture](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/850673/proper-currency-format-when-not-displaying-the-native-currency-of-a-culture)

Comment: Also `Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}Here is the same value displayed in currency form: {1}", Environment.NewLine, value.ToString("C2")));`

Comment: @BobKaufman - I think these are much closer duplicates since they are .Net specific: [String format currency](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10416553/string-format-currency) and [Format decimal as currency based on currency code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13364984/format-decimal-as-currency-based-on-currency-code).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check out [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/syy068tk(v=vs.90).aspx) for currency formatting for certain cultures.

Here's [another](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/syy068tk(v=vs.90).aspx) that has a list for formatting numeric strings.

Hope this helps! :D

Comment: This post contains [no content](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/). Please copy in relevant portions from the links you give, in case they bitrot.

Answer (score 4):

From the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/syy068tk(v=vs.90).aspx) documentation

```
// Creates a CultureInfo for English in the U.S.
CultureInfo us = new CultureInfo("en-US");
// Display i formatted as currency for us.
Console.WriteLine(i.ToString("c", us));
```

So if you want to change it to Euro just change `en-US` to any country that uses Euro like `fr-FR`

Answer (score 1):

Check this out:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/syy068tk(v=vs.90).aspx

Different Cultures: Allows you to display it in any currency format you want.

Answer (score 1):

See this msdn article here.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb688126.aspx

Essentialy, your machine has a configured Locale which determines how the currency is formatted. If someone in a different country were to run your app, they'd see a different money format (assuming they use different currency).

If your using a webapp, you'll need to get the format of your connected client

Answer (score 1):

You can get Euros for a specific language, by using the C# code you already used and simply adding the language. [Microsoft has a useful page on string formatting.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx)

So, to change your code to Euros,it is a simple fix:

```
Console.WriteLine("\nHere is the same value displayed in currency form: " + value.ToString("C2",fr-FR));
```

Comment: I'm not sure whether to upvote your answer because it gets the right idea across, or downvote it because you think you're a [C programmer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11695126/712526).

Comment: Haha! Wow. Whoops!