# How can I format a number to curreny with differend decimal signs

Tags: c#, formatting

I'ts possible to format a number to a currency with differend decimals?

For example:

```
// for numbers I can use the placeholder #
decimal d1 = 1.2345;
decimal d2 = 1.23;
String.Format("{0:0.####}", d1); //results in 1.2345
String.Format("{0:0.####}", d2); //results in 1.23

// with the format specifier C I cannot use the placeholder
String.Format("{0:C4}", d1); //results in 1.2345 €
String.Format("{0:C4}", d2); //results in 1.2300 €

// I need something like this
String.Format("{0:C####}", d1); //results in 1.2345 €
String.Format("{0:C####}", d2); //results in 1.23 €

// I don't want to use this solution because I use my program in different countries
String.Format("{0:0.#### €}", d1); //results in 1.2345 €
String.Format("{0:0.#### €}", d2); //results in 1.23 €
```

Anyone have an idea?

Thank you!

Comment: [Possible duplicate of Format decimal as currency based on currency code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13364984/format-decimal-as-currency-based-on-currency-code/30628398)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is your answer:

```
double value = 12345.6789;
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("C", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture));
```

If you want more than 2 decimal digits (let's say 3 digits after decimal points), then it would be

```
double value = 12345.6789;
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("C3", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture));
```

This is assuming that your application will be executed under different cultures.  That's why we used `currentCulture`.

Otherwise you can create instance of `CultureInfo` depending on the culture you want to use.

Refer [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings) for number formatting and [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo?view=netframework-4.8) for more details on `CultureInfo`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I want show 3 digits, if 3 digits exists. And if exists only 2 digits, I want show 2 digits. But I see, that this in combination with the currency specifier C is not possible...