# how to change the default currency in visual basic 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

In visual basic 2010 my default is dollar sign "$". How can I change the default currency of mine country which is Malaysia with a sign of "RM". Thanks in advance.

***EDIT**

Basically when I entered these code, it doesn't work. Can I know why?

Private Sub Button1_Click ......

Dim a As Integer = 400

Dim ri As System.Globalization.RegionInfo = New System.Globalization.RegionInfo(New CultureInfo("ms-MY").LCID)

Console.WriteLine(ri.CurrencySymbol)

MsgBox(a.ToString("C"))

End Sub

Comment: Did you obtain the Windows license for your machine legally?

Comment: I have my project to be done within a month so I acquired the trial version of the visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

You should try setting the culture of your thread or get info for a relevant thread. Using this way you can retrieve [culture specific currency code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763128/get-the-currency-from-current-culture).

**EDIT: **

```
var ri = new System.Globalization.RegionInfo(new CultureInfo("ms-MY").LCID);
Console.WriteLine(ri.CurrencySymbol);  // Output `RM`
```

Have a look at [this url](http://www.csharp-examples.net/culture-names/) for list of culture supported.

**EDIT :** (VB.Net version)

```
Dim ri as System.Globalization.RegionInfo = new System.Globalization.RegionInfo(new CultureInfo("ms-MY").LCID)
Console.WriteLine(ri.CurrencySymbol)  // Output `RM`
```

Comment: Sorry but could I know where to set the culture of my thread, I am a beginner in using visual basic. I get the code from the side but I don't know where should I type.

Comment: @user3425675 Check the code and - cough - the documentation ;)

Comment: Can I have the code for visual basic rather than code for C# cause I don't know any thing about the C# language. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This caught my eye and I thought to provide this solution. To make the CultureInfo class work in Visual Basic you'll need code like this:

```
Imports System.Globalization

Public Class .......

Private Sub Button1_Click ......
Dim a As Integer = 400
Dim ri As CulturInfo = New CultureInfo("ms-MY")

MsgBox(a.ToString("C",ri))

End Sub
End Class
```