# How to get 3 digit/letter currencyCode from 3 digit ISO countryCode

Tags: c#, sql, cultureinfo, regioninfo

I have a ddl with values that represent country codes. eg. BRA, THA, UKR, AUS etc.
I need to get the preferred currency from localization settings for each of these.

I have tried checking the RegionInfo class and it is likely that the answer is somewhere in there. This link shows what i want https://www.iban.com/currency-codes

**Is there any way to get the 3 digit currencyCode without using a table structure?** i.e. from the pc or browser itself. Basically, if the user chooses their country as USA, then the currency should be fixed to USD. I can do this very easily with some sql. But i would like to do this without hitting the db. i.e. via RegionInfo or CultureInfo.

I cannot use 
new RegionInfo(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.LCID).ISOCurrencySymbol as it pulls from the server.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the currency from current culture?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763128/get-the-currency-from-current-culture)

Comment: No it's not possible with 3 custom chars like you explain here, you must use a reference table (or DB or inside Code)

Comment: There are many [API](https://www.iban.com/developers)s, its a good bet you can find there what you are looking for, [currency-converter-api](https://www.iban.com/currency-converter-api) for example.

Comment: Nope @TanveerBadar. The accepted solution there gives the current culture of the server.

Comment: Do you get Accept-Language header in the request? That can give you a culture info.

Comment: why was this question downvoted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a solution about it if that 3 letter is ISO standard you can apply this code

```
var c = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures)
      .Select(t=> new RegionInfo(t.LCID))
      .Where(t=>t.ThreeLetterISORegionName  == "USA")
      .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

.NET has `CultureInfo.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol`

```
RegionInfo us = new RegionInfo("en-US");
RegionInfo gb = new RegionInfo("en-GB");
RegionInfo fr = new RegionInfo("fr-FR");

Console.Out.WriteLine(us.CurrencySymbol); // $
Console.Out.WriteLine(gb.CurrencySymbol); // £
Console.Out.WriteLine(fr.CurrencySymbol); // €

Console.Out.WriteLine(us.ISOCurrencySymbol); // USD
Console.Out.WriteLine(gb.ISOCurrencySymbol); // GBP
Console.Out.WriteLine(fr.ISOCurrencySymbol); // EUR
```

The complete Region information is available [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-lcid/a9eac961-e77d-41a6-90a5-ce1a8b0cdb9c?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Answer (score -1):

You will need to have access to a datastore somewhere.

Your choices are:

1. database - which you've already discounted (probably as you don't want to maintain the dataset)
2. hard code - again that requires you to maintain the dataset again.
3. use an external data source - such as an API, where the third party can provide the data you require in response to an HTTP request. The bonus is that they also maintain the dataset for you (although there will be no guarantees of how regularly it is kept up to date).

I suggest that you have a look at:

https://restcountries.eu/

They provide a range of RESTful API endpoints that you could query to retrieve the currency code.

Comment: I stated in the question that i do not want to use a table structure.

Comment: Agreed, and I acknowledged that in point 1. My suggestion was to use an API which would return the value for you.